# @SceneStorage behaves inconsistently in my code

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm learning how to use `@SceneStorage` and create the following simple code.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @SceneStorage("text") var text: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(text)")
            
            Button("CLICK") {
                text += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I click the button to change the text value, swipe to terminate the app, then reopen the app. But sometimes the text keeps the latest value, sometimes it starts from `0` again. Can someone explain how `@SceneStorage` works. Thank you so much.

Comment: SceneStorage does not guaranty persistency over termination - read documentation.

Comment: Sounds to me like you need AppStorage